# MVC 5 - ASP.NET Identity - Token colum empty in email confirmation

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, email-validation

When calling **UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken()** I get a token, but the ConfirmationToken column in AspNetUsers table is left empty. Does this method suppose to put the token there automatically, and if so where do I tell it the name of the column to look for. Or maybe I need to manually put the token there myself after calling it ?

(Also the EmailConfirmed column in AspNetUsers stays False after calling UserManager.ConfirmEmail but I presume it happens for the same reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ConfirmationToken column by default in Identity 2.0, are you sure this isn't something you added in your user class?

Comment: My mistake. Yes I added it manually. UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken() works just fine. The question is irrelevant.